# Select 1 column from a Group By LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I think what I need is relatively simple but every example I Google just returns results using `First()`, which I'm already doing. Here is my expression:

```
var options = configData.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row["myColumn"]).Select(grp => grp.First());
```

What I need is only ONE column from the `grp` portion and to be able to suffix `.ToList()` on there without an error. As it stands I receive 4 columns, but only need a specific one, kind of like if this `(grp => grp["myColumn"])`, didn't result in error the Error `153    Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<object,System.Data.DataRow>'`

Also, `Key` does not work in the grouping portion as these results are from a `DataTable` object. See here - > [image]

Comment: does `configData.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row["myColumn"]).Select(grp => grp.Key).ToList();` not work for you?

Comment: After grouping, you have multiple groups, each group having one key and the group items. Is your single column the group key? If it is not, since you have multiple items in each group, column of which item in the group will you select?

Answer (score 4):

If you want only the keys, you can use

```
var options = configData.AsEnumerable().Select(row=>row["myColumn"]).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that this is what you want:

```
configData.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r["myColumn"])
    .Select(g => new
    {
        myColumnValue = g.Key, 
        myColumnItems = g.Select(r => r["OtherColumn"]).ToList()
    });
```

Do you understand how/what this does though? Try it out and inspect the resulting IEnumerable. I'm not sure you have a perfect understanding on how GroupBy works but take your time with above example.

See this part:

```
new
{
    myColumnValue = g.Key, 
    myColumnItems = g.Select(r => r["OtherColumn"]).ToList()
}
```

This creates an anonymous type which outputs the values of "OtherColumn" column into a list grouped by "myColumn" where value of "myColumn" is in the myColumnValue property.

I'm not sure this answers your question but it looks like this is what you want.

The variable `g` is of the type `IGrouping<object, DataRow>`, it's not `DataRow`. The `IGrouping` interface is designed to provide a list of *DataRow's* grouped by *object* values - it does not produce a flat list, if it did then it would just be a Sort, not GroupBy.

Comment: This is probably what I need, how do I handle `Null`s in the column name though? They are causing errors.

Comment: @Volearix if you have a `null` in your values you can use this `.GroupBy(r => r["myColumn"] ?? "SomeNullString")`. If you have `DBNull` you can do something similar. You can manipulate `r["myColumn"]` any way you want in a lambda expression similar to an `if` statement. I will edit the answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the field you want after your call to First() e.g.

```
.Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()["MyFieldName"]);
```

This will take the first record from the grouping and select the specified field from that record.